# p:commandButton displayed twice after navigating back to page

Tags: jsf, primefaces, commandbutton

I have tab registers with a `p:commantButton`. By clicking on this button I load an entry list in a `p:dataTable` (about 10,000) to make some selections (navigated to another page). My selection is added to my `p:dataTable` on the `p:tabView`, where i clicked on the button. After comming back to the page the two buttons are displayed twice and a click on the same button does not call my java method any more until I refresh the page completely.

Any Idea ?
thanks for your help

[my tabview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mR6BE.png)

Comment: Post your xhtml page

Comment: @Sarz: No, an [mcve] should be posted...! See also http://www.stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info

Comment: Are you somewhere using `binding` attribute to a bean which is not in request scope?